# How can I move my child component to new parent in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm rendering a list of child components which contain a checkbox, and when that checkbox is clicked, I want to move that child component inside another div element.

[image] Here's an image of what my app looks nice. I'd like to check the student names and move them up, under the "Present" sub-heading..

```
let ClassComp = (props) => {
  const { teacher, subject, students, day } = props.classOf

  const renderStudents = (students) => {
    if (students && students.length > 0) {
      return (
        <div>
          {students.map((student, index) =>
            <StudentCheckbox key={index} student={student} handleCheckboxClick={handleCheckboxClick} />
          )}
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return <p style={{ margin: '10px' }} >No students registered.</p>
    }
  }

  const handleCheckboxClick = (elId) => {
    const presentStudentEl = document.getElementById('present-students')

    // move StudentCheckbox element inside this element ^
  }

  return (
    <div className="ui segment" style={segmentStyle} >
      <div className="content">
        <div className="ui medium header">{teacher} - {subject}</div>
        <div className="ui divider"></div>
        <div className="ui sub header">Students</div>
        <div className="ui tiny header">Present:
          <div id="present-students"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="ui tiny header">Absent:
          <div id="absent-students">
            {renderStudents(students)}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: '30px' }}>
          <button className="mini compact ui negative right floated button"
            onClick={() => setModalVisible(true)}>Delete Class
          </button>
          <Link to={`/todaysclass/edit/${props.classId}`} className="mini compact ui right floated button">Edit Class</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { classOf: state.classes[ownProps.classId] }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteClass })(ClassComp)
```

and here's my child component:

```
const StudentCheckbox = (props) => {
  const uniqId = idGenerator()
  return (
    <div className="field" style={{ margin: '5px' }}>
      <div className="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id={uniqId} onChange={() => props.handleCheckboxClick(uniqId)} />
        <label htmlFor={uniqId}>{props.student}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you'll need a state for your component. Take a look in the docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

So basically, besides `props` (which are "fixed"), you'll have a `state`, which will change when you check the items.

Your `render` method will use the state to place the items either in one div, or the other. So all you have to do is use `setState` to change the state and the render method will redraw the new one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So all I need is a state object in my parent component? 
But how do I change where I render my child component?

Comment: @NewbieDev90 You use that state to do some `if` statements in your render method. That controls where the childs will render.

Answer (score 1):

You're using redux to manage state. That's good. It helps properly manage/manipulate data.

In this case you're trying to decorate a view without data changes [in redux store] - that's not good, it doesn't even make sense in react.

Rendered components/view is only a [derived] **V**iew from a **M**odel(state) - in MVC. Moving some element from one div to another in DOM (if you implement this) doesn't change the [base] state - after rerendering you'll loose these kind of changes.

---

UPDATE:

You should keep students' presence in the store (default false). **You need a separate action** (with params/payload: `classId`, `studentId`), call API (in action creator to save attendence) **and reducer** for change 'flag' in redux store.

Each `student` will have `isPresent` property. You can simply change your `renderStudents` to render both divs (additional boolean argument and apriopriate filtering at the beginning).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm having difficulty understanding it. Is what I'm trying to do quite unorthodox? 
Yeah I had definitely thought about writing up another action creator and reducer for this, but I just couldn't figure it out..

Comment: Start with action for adding (and removing) student to class? Moving will be very similiar.

Comment: The students are all already in a class. I have two "class" components shown in my OP. I would like to move each student component in the class, from "Absent" to the div tag "Present", like keeping a record of attendance (though I am not sure how to keep this record...which is a whole different matter)
So if I understand you correctly, I should store the checked value of my student checkboxes in the store right? And when that changes, my component will re-render with the updated position of the student component?